# ng is called instead of git when I use rebase or another flags

Tags: angular, git, shell, angular-cli, gitkraken

Hello I have a machine in my job, with angular-cli and git installed.

The problem is that when I try to do `git rebase`, or another "complex" git command, this returns the following:

> The specified command ("/home/user/project/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG") is invalid. For a list of available options,
>       run "ng help".
>
> Did you mean "make-this-awesome"?

I try to solve this, uninstalling npm, and ng, but doesn't work.

The `$PATH` is the following:

> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/user/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/user/Android/Sdk/tools

but when I use gitkraken for example this error doesn't happen

Any idea that how to solve it?

Comment: Search for `ng` calls in `.git/hooks/`. Something like `grep -Fw ng .git/hooks/*`.

Comment: It does not return anything, but anyway, in that repo there are no hooks

Comment: It sounds like you've configured your commit-message-editor incorrectly. What is the setting of `$GIT_EDITOR`, `core.editor`, `$VISUAL`, and/or `$EDITOR`?

Comment: All variables return empty, and with `git config --list | xargs grep -r "ng"` dosen't return nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally work updating the editor with nano, `git config --global core.editor 'nano'`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with a `ng` error when trying to use `visudo`.

It turns out that visudo (and I guess possibly git) uses the editor defined by the link `/usr/bin/editor`, which in my config points to another link `/etc/alternatives/editor`, which somehow ended up defined as `/usr/bin/ng`...

Resetting that last link to an actual editor (here vim) solved the problem for me :

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/vim /etc/alternatives/editor
```

Comment: The right way to update alternatives is with `update-alternatives` rather than a brute-force `ln` :)